# Как получить доступ к значениям мотируемых элементов на React в браузере?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Есть сайт написаный на `React` (**сторонний**, к нему доступа нету). На главной страце есть карточка товаров с ценами и блок с пагинацией условных страниц. По нажатию на "ссылки" пагинации `React` обновляет значения в карточках товара.

Вопрос - Как в консоль получать значения новых значений цен **после монтирования нового контента**.

Вопрос именно в том, что это чужой DOM... и нужна показывать только визуальный вывод.
Была идея так, это сделать...

```
window.onload = function() {
  const root = document.getElementById('center'); /// Это глобальный элемент в котором находяться карточка товаров
  const listItems = root.querySelectorAll('li');
  
  listItems.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
      showMeFullPrices(); /// тут выполнение функции обработки данных. Не рботает
    });
  });
};
```

В консоле браузера. Не работает.
Также была идея вешать таймер срабатываний, после нажатия на ссылку пагинции. Что б в консоль цены показывались, только после того как пройдет какой-то промежуток времени - тоже не отработало, функция отрабатывает мгновенно, а при монтировании нового контента ничего не показывает...

Подскажите как бы это решить ?
Идеи по типу

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const updateContent = () => {
    // добавить сюда необходимый JS код для обновления содержимого страницы
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    updateContent();
  });

  return (
    // JSX компоненты
  );
}
```

не предлать, поскольку к Реакт компонентам в браузере не достучаться (ну или я не нашйл как).

Comment: Как вы собрались менять код, если доступа к коду сайта у вас нет?

Comment: через браузер. Там есть консоль и туда можна вводить значения и команды. По сути задача сводиться к работе с чужим дом деревом. Что-то по типу того как работает AdBlock

Comment: Как вариант, использовать `MutationObserver` на некоем "ключевом" элементе. Т.о. при его изменении ты получишь список того что изменилось. Или это просто будет сигналом что данные обновились и можно анализировать новый ДОМ... https://learn.javascript.ru/mutation-observer